# Unable to generate the vector tiles from geoJson using tippecanoe

Tags: maps, mapbox, geojson, vector-tiles, tippecanoe

I am trying to convert the geoJson files into vector files using [mapbox/tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe). I have build the tippecanoe image as mention in the document. But when I run the below command nothing happens.

docker run -it --rm \
  -v /tiledata:/data \
  tippecanoe:latest \
  tippecanoe --output=/data/output.mbtiles /data/example.geojson

It shows me the messages like

> For layer 0, using name "example"
>   /data/example.geojson: No such file or directory
>   0 features, 10 bytes of geometry, 4 bytes of seperate metadata, 0 bytes of string pool.
>   Did not read any valid geometries

In my data folder there is example.geojson file exists but it still not able to find end.

I running this on Ubuntu 14 machine.

Can anybody help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to fix this by running the command inside the data folder where the json files exists. The worked command will be "sudo tippecanoe -o output.mbtiles -z5 example.json"

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this question while trying to convert a geojson file with an existing Docker image from [Klokantech](https://hub.docker.com/r/klokantech/tippecanoe/).

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/osm klokantech/tippecanoe tippecanoe /osm/netherlands-rcn.geojson -o /osm/netherlands-rcn.mbtiles
```

Using this image converting went really easy.